# A Question of Truthfulness and Possible Application

Tags: complex-analysis

A professor gave me the following statement:If $g$ is analytic on $D$ and $\int_{\beta}g(z)\, dz=0$ for any piece-wise simple smooth closed curve (let $z_0$ be a fixed point) and define $G(z)=\int_{\beta}g(z)\, dz$ where $\beta$ is any curve from $z_0$ to $z$. Then, 
$$\mbox{1) $G$ is well-defined and analytic.}$$
$$\mbox{2) $G'=g$.}$$

Is it true and if and is so can I get an example of how to apply it?

Comment: I assume you mean that $D$ is an open and path-connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$, $z_0 \in D$, and $G:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is defined $G(z) = \int_{\beta} g(z)dz$ where $\beta$ is any [simple smooth closed curve from $z_0$ to $z$ that is contained in $D$].

Comment: In that case it does seem that $G(z)$ is well defined (independent of the path $\beta$) and $G'(z)=g(z)$. It seems this is the case whenever $g(z)$ is continuous on $D$ with the property $\int_{\beta} g(z)dz=0$, I don't know why $g$ is assumed to be analytic. I suppose that if $g$ has those properties than it _must_ be analytic.

Comment: This is the exact statement he had on the board.

Comment: I'm probably over-complicating this quite a bit. If you want to apply this theorem on say $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(z)=(1-e^z+\cos(z)$(which is analytic everywhere and satisfies all conditions) over the path that contains initial point $z_0=1$ and ending point $c=2$. Then all I do is find $F(z)$ such that $F'(z)=f(z)$. Then, I just solve the integral by plugging in which in this case I would get $F(2)-F(1)$ where $F(z)=z-e^z+\sin(z)$. If so, what is literally the point besides to tell us how to compute a normal integral.

Comment: I think the point of the statement written this way is to provide a statement that you can prove using concepts of path integration.  The converse statement is more useful: If $G(z)$ is a function with continuous complex derivative $G'(z)=g(z)$, then integrating over $g$ is independent of path.  This can be viewed as a generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int_a^b f'(t)dt = f(b)-f(a)$ (depends only on the endpoints).  In the complex domain the result is more interesting $\int_{\beta_{ab}} g(z)dz = G(b)-G(a)$ for $\beta_{ab}$ _any_ simple smooth path from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: The reason the complex generalization is more interesting is that in the 1-dimensional case (fundamental theorem of calculus) there is only one way to get from point $a$ to point $b$ on the 1-d real number line.  But in the 2-d complex plane there are many paths you can use to get from $a$ to $b$, and the integral is the same regardless of which path you use. [You need the domain to be "path connected" since otherwise there may be no path from $a$ to $b$.]